# Multiple MuiThemeProvider for material ui?

Tags: reactjs, themes, material-ui

I have multiple `Paper` components, and each of them have a different background color.

Do i simply wrap each of the components around a `MuiThemeProvider` with custom theme?

Or is `MuiThemeProvider` meant to be one per application (like Redux)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With material-ui 1.0, it is possible to have independent or nested MuiThemeProviders. So you can have various areas of your app themed independently. Here's the link to the corresponding documentation: [Nested Themes](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#theme-nesting)